# What service to use for Meteor App deploy?

Tags: meteor, heroku, web-deployment, digital-ocean

I need Meteor App in production, without worrying about scaling in the future. App will have 500 user online in any one time - as maximum. I read in the oficial guide that the best practice for many reasons is deploy to Galaxy.
But there are also many articles about deploy to Digital Ocean and Heroku.

So what variant is the best?

Comment: I deployed my meteor app in DigitalOcean using mupx. Using mupx is smooth. I have not checked it for Meteor 1.4.

Comment: @Vijay thank you for your response! how did you solved the problem with seo (in galaxy it is possible to use prerender as an option)? Do youhost Mongo and images on the same DO droplet? Can you tell, approximately how much do you spent per month for your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use digitalocean.

Set up nameservers, set up node on your droplet and have Mupx do the deploying. It's very easy and DO is cheap.

DO has easy to follow tutorials to do the initial setup and you will thank me later + your wallet will be happy.

Comment: thank you for response! do you mean tuts like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx) ? there are [different pricing variants](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/), which one do you recommend for the project with 150 connections at any one time as maximum?

Comment: I have the $20/month plan and it holds 100 connections fine. Plus my app is pretty resource intensive (where I upload user's spreadsheets, map out all financial data and make it available via graphs and charts and detailed analysis). So I think the $20/month will be more than enough for most cases.

Comment: one more question please, how did you solve the problem of seo with meteor app? i know that meteor apps are client rendered, so google doesn't index the well. it is necessary for my project to be seo optimized. on the other side Galaxy provides seo instrument (prerender).

Comment: I personally use `tomwasd:flow-router-seo` for my SEO to do simple tag inputs and other essential functions necessary for crawlers. My website is ranked in Google and indexed, so it's working in that regard. However, overall, I don't really focus too much on SEO since Meteor, by itself, was never meant to be SEO friendly in the first place. It's a platform for real-time apps to be built and maximize user experience and user interaction. A small package like the one above is all that's really necessary.

Comment: Also, if you want the same SEO rendering as in Galaxy, just add prerender.io to your app via `dfischer:prerenderio` package.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Galaxy in a production level app for one of our clients and it works fantastic. If you want a deployment where you don't have to worry about scaling at all, then Galaxy is for you.

With time, as your users increase and you find yourself needing more resources, you can assign better containers and CPU power with just the click of one button. It also provides complete logs and some performance metrics to help you in a completely meteor-specific manner.

The deployment process itself is as simple as having a settings json file, and running a one line command like:

```
DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=galaxy.meteor.com meteor deploy appname.meteorapp.com --settings settings.json
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! the problem is the cost of Galaxy. Can you tell me please, approximately how much did you spent per month for your app in production?

If I understand correctly I also need something like mLab in addition to Galaxy (to host MongoDB), right?

I am planning to have 150 connections at any one moment as a maximum.

Comment: Yes, you will need to have a database hosting to use with Galaxy. I used mLab initially and then moved to compose.io for oplog support. Both are great services. It is true that Galaxy is quite premium.. cost the client around $150-$250 monthly depending on configuration and number of containers used. If this is too costly for you then you could try Digital Ocean as it's very affordable, however the performance may be lower.